# Which of the two php codes is better

Tags: php

When you are posting a form back to itself using php, which code is better to use:

```
PHP_SELF or REQUEST_URI?
```

Comment: They are two different things. `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` is the request uri like `/question/123` and `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` is the path to the script the webserver ends up calling like `/classes/question/Qeustion.inc`. If you're not using any rewriting they are the same, but if you are then it totally depends on which one you want ..

Comment: so when navigating back to your own page is it better retriving the url or path to script?

Comment: Sorry, did not see you finishing comment 'If you're not using any rewriting they are the same, but if you are then it totally depends on which one you want'

Answer (score 0):

neither. use this:

```
<form action=''>
```

Comment: That won't do anything in some browsers (older Operas, I think). No submit, no nothing. However, `action='?'` will work fine.

Comment: I would argue that it's best to always use absolute URLs. Neither `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` or `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` will help you with this.

Comment: @Piskvor Might as well figure out how to make it compatible with Netscape. lol **rolls eyes**

Comment: ya, you can just write a function called something like site_url() that will give you the base url everytime.  Kind of like code igniter or other frameworks.  It makes a site way more portable too.

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte: Well, believe it or not, some users are still using browsers the age of NN (IE6, for example). As a web developer, I'm not really in a position fit to change that; not very directly anyway.

Comment: @JohnB Yep, another good idea! I use smarty, and set a php constant to {$site_url} for universal use within view files.

Comment: @Piskvor I'm just being playful. You certainly have a point. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server software, use REQUEST_URI under linux and PHP_SELF under windows then for speed. Source: http://sniptools.com/vault/php_self-getenv-request_uri-or-script_name

Comment: I don't think it is. The webserver ensures it's there (Apache does anyway). Some `$_SERVER` variables are user controlled, like `HTTP_REFERER` but not this one I believe.

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` is everything to the right of the domain name in a URL, so if your url is: `http://example.org/funny/form.php`, then `REQUEST_URI` will be "/funny/form.php"

This is what you want to do:

```
<form action="<?php echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
</form>
```

This will send the form to the same URL as the visitor is at.

Note: When making GET requests, also the get variables are in REQUEST_URI. So if your URL is: `http://example.org/funny/form.php?name=obama`, then `REQUEST_URI` will be "/funny/form.php?name=obama", which is not what you want as action attribute in your form element. This is not a problem if you are using POST request. If you are using GET requests, then you have to cut REQUEST_URI at the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the FULL url, so use `REQUEST_URI` and write a function to generate a the full URL and insert it into the form. An alternative would be to use `""`, to submit to the current page.

You would not need to use `PHP_SELF`, but if you do, please be aware of the [dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507830/getting-pagename-using-php-self-dangers).